# How can I crawl the web to find links / sites around a topic?

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, bigdata

I don't really know where to begin with this project so excuse the vague title.

When I google 'How to Program', I want the results of that search in some workable form. I don't know if I can somehow use Google, or some other search for this, but if not, how can I build my own software to be able to get this data? How does google run it's search?

I know JavaScript and NodeJS - what else will I need to learn possibly? (I imagine some sort of database for sure).

Answer (score 1):

[MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) ([mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/)) for storing your data and [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (headless browser for serverside) for scraping would be your best bet. I'm currently working on a webcrawler for crawling websites with a combination of the two. It works pretty well.

You're going to want to use PhantomJ to load up google, type in your search, and grab the html from the page. You can then process the HTML using a library like [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio). It is a serverside jquery like library for DOM parsing.

Then just go through and click the next page of results and repeat the above steps as much as your want. Gathering the information you need from each page and storing it in mongo.

There's lots of other things you'll have to worry about like how to handle captchas, ip blocking etc. But the above should get you started.

Comment: I guess my main question is: How does Google know which sites to crawl? I get that once you have a link, you can find out the pages in it and crawl the HTML, but how do I know the universe of all sites that exist?

Comment: Google probably finds links on other sites that point to other websites (these are known as `backlinks`). They then add new websites to be crawled to a big queue. They also probably look up new DNS records for new sites and add those to be crawled.

Comment: So, you want a list of a specified number of the ranking websites for the search query 'How to Program'. Is your end goal just a list of all the links? Or do you want to crawl each individual site for some sort of data? Just a few questions to think about.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't have any idea of how Google went about figuring out which sites to index but from what you're saying it sounds like a somewhat manual process that is more art than science? That is, they could technically miss obbotoodala.com even it exists but somehow Google didn't see it's DNS records / is yet to be linked from another site.

Comment: Here's my idea: crawl for links that might be of value towards a specific goal: "Learn How to Program", then run some sort of algorithm on it to reduce the total number of links, then I want to run some manual curation on it - with the eventual goal being to find the best links. How is this different than Google itself? Because I want to focus on identifying links or sites that are actionable rather than just pure information or knowledge.

Comment: Honestly, that sounds exactly like what google is doing. Except how would you measure what 'actionable' means? That sounds like a manual process to me and is really based on the context of what you're searching for.